# Gitlab cannot clone over HTTP after upgrade to 6.5

Tags: http, clone, gitlab

After upgrading gitlab from 6.3 to 6.5, everything looks good, except I cannot clone any repositories over HTTP. I could clone/fetch/push over SSH, and also browse the whole repositories over HTTP, but just cannot clone it over HTTP.
The error message is:

```
$ git clone http://mydomain/mygroup/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: 3ca
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any hints are appreciated.

====== More Information =======

When executing the clone as above, there are two nginx logs:

```
192.168.1.103 - - [26/Feb/2014:17:51:58 +0800] "GET /mygroup/test.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 283 "-" "git/1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)" "-"

192.168.1.103 - - [26/Feb/2014:17:51:58 +0800] "POST /mygroup/test.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 994 "-" "git/1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)" "-"
```

And here is the error I got when trying to "git fetch" inside a project which was cloned over HTTP before:

```
$ git fetch
fatal: git fetch_pack: expected ACK/NAK, got '
0038ACK 12c5f4a0f130acfd8ef502a28989f42d37228016 common
0038ACK 736453e9369a9bb91b2b49b17419c168e4b61c5b common
0031ACK 736453e9369a9bb91b2b49b17419c168e4b61c5b
0022Counting objects: 114, done.
002eCompressing objects: 100% (67/67), done.
2004PACK'
```

Comment: Would https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3384#issuecomment-15457287 help?

Comment: Thanks, but tried it and it doesn't help. I'm using IP as server name, so it's not the same cause.

Comment: Finally I found it's a known issue: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5774 . The solution is to upgrade nginx to 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) could add a more explicit/precise error message than `expected ACK/NAK`.
That would help explaining the particular clone error in the OP's case.

See [commit 8e2c7be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e2c7bef034f0712c6db776974ee4b40f1150a56) (12 Apr 2017) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d2617eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2617eb98440a43072c49e416e0986ef3231faa4), 24 Apr 2017)</sup>

> ### `fetch-pack`: show clearer error message upon `ERR`
>
> Currently, fetch-pack prints a confusing error message ("`expected ACK/NAK`") when the server it's communicating with sends a `pkt-line` starting with "`ERR`".
>   Replace it with a less confusing error message.
>
> Also update the documentation describing the `fetch-pack/upload-pack`
>   protocol ([`pack-protocol.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8e2c7bef034f0712c6db776974ee4b40f1150a56/Documentation/technical/pack-protocol.txt#L354-L356)) to indicate that "`ERR`" can be sent in the place of "`ACK`" or "`NAK`".
>   In practice, this has been done for quite some
>   time by other Git implementations (e.g. JGit sends "`want $id not valid`")
>   and by Git itself (since commit [bdb31ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdb31eada76fd27d18e981c3b40889297fa889c6): "`upload-pack`: report "`not our ref`" to client", 2017-02-23) whenever a "`want`" line references an object that it does not have. (This is uncommon, but can happen if a repository is garbage-collected during a negotiation.)